# Diff function doesn't work when compiled

Tags: matlab

I wrote a simple program to find the roots of a non-linear equation using numerical method known as Newton Raphson method, thus i need to calculate the derivative of function at some points.
I use function "diff" which takes a string and returns its derivation then i use eval to calculate the slope of tangent line:

```
func='sin(x^2)';
x=4.5;
slope=eval(diff(func));
```

The code is inside a .m file which is along some other .fig files.
Everything just seems to be fine when i debug/run it in GUIDE environment or via MATLAB's command window, there's only a warning that the function will be deprecated in a future release.
But when i compile the files with the following command: "mcc -e file1 file2", and run the .exe it throws runtime error when it reaches that specific line with "diff" and beeps!
Is there any other way to calculate the derivative (symbolic/non-numerical) that'd be also supported in an application file?

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/06/19/writing-deployable-code/#13). The problem is `func` not `diff`. Can you not use an alternative to defining the function as a string? If possible, make func a normal function file and then include it in the deployed package.

Comment: The function is given via UI by the user so it's not defined or an exact function.

Comment: Oh i see. In that case, using function strings and eval will not work. You could either design a calculator-style interface and have them input expressions by clicking appropriate buttons or you could try parsing a user-typed expression into it's matlab function counterparts. The latter sounds painful though.